# Can I receive and spend money on PayPal without linking it to my bank account?

Tags: paypal, france

Two questions:

- Can I create a PayPal account and receive €200 (or a similar amount) without adding a bank account, credit card, or anything but my email address?
- Can I then use that money to buy on Amazon, still without adding anything but my email address? If not, can I buy gift cards and use those on Amazon?

I am in France.

Comment: Paypal needs to follow rules based on country of its member, what country are you in, and have you looked at their web site?

Comment: France, and I couldn't find anything

Comment: amazon doesn't let you use Paypal. You can get paypal credit card and use it to buy things as a normal credit card from a bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Bluetie Grasper have said.

> Can I create a PayPal account and receive €200 (or a similar amount) without adding a bank account, credit card, or anything but my email address?

The answer is No. You can transfer the money to your PayPal account but until you verify it with your personal information with at least a credit card or mostly likely a bank account, PayPal will hold those funds until otherwise.

> Can I then use that money to buy on Amazon, still without adding anything but my email address? If not, can I buy gift cards and use those on Amazon?

Amazon does not accept PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly my own experience : no you can't.
Paypal will block the money even if it's only for online payement.